# Unexpected end of JSON input when requiring a JSON file

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

When using fs.writeFile I create a JSON file that looks like:

```
[{"schoolname":"Scottsdale","StudentFirst":"john","StudentLast":"smith","grade":"2","email":"john@smith.com","ParentLast":"Smith","ParentFirst":"John"}]
```

Except right after when I require the same file I get the error:

```
Unexpected end in JSON input
```

I've done this same thing before but using bigger data and it seemed to work fine.

```
await fs.writeFile(`./${fileName}.json`, 
JSON.stringify(result.recordsets[0]), function(err) {
     if(err) {
           return console.log(err)
     }
})
const file = require(`./${fileName}.json`)
```

Expected results should return the JSON above so I can have a copy of the file and iterate through it.

Comment: Sounds like you should validate the JSON.

Comment: You can't `await` callback-based functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is the result of requiring an empty JSON file. The JSON file is empty because `fs.writeFile` is asynchronous, and you're using `await` improperly.

1. You need to use `await` inside of an async function
2. You can only use `await` with promises, not callbacks

Option 1: use `fs.writeFileSync`

```
fs.writeFileSync(
  `./${fileName}.json`, 
  JSON.stringify(result.recordsets[0])
)
const file = require(`./${fileName}.json`)
```

Option 2: wrap `fs.writeFile` in a promise

```
(async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(
      `./${fileName}.json`, 
      JSON.stringify(result.recordsets[0]),
      function(err) {
        if (err) {
          reject()
          return console.log(err)
        }
        resolve()
      }
    )
  });
  const file = require(`./${fileName}.json`)
})();
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```js
import fsPromises from 'fs/promises';
import path from 'path';

export async function setLocalData(locale: string, path: string, data: any) {
  if (path)
    try {
      const readJsonData = JSON.parse(
        await fsPromises.readFile(filePath, 'utf8'),
      );
      readJsonData[locale + path] = data;
      const writejsonData = JSON.stringify(readJsonData);
      await fsPromises.writeFile(filePath, writejsonData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
    }
}
```